# Just change html page's section via refinary cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I need to display advertisements in a particular section of html page in my rails app. My client wants me to use refinery cms to create advertisements from admin end.

Is it possible to use a section of already existing html page via refinery cms?

Thanks!!!